# Jquery 1.11.1 - download file and additional callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, file, download

I have form which i submit to django server by calling.

```
$("#my_form").submit();
```

It server returns xml file by executing this code:

```
content = some_data_retrieved_from_database_as_xml()
response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/xml')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; '
response['Content-Disposition'] += 'filename=my_file.xml'
response['Content-Encoding'] = 'UTF-8'
return response
```

Google Chrome only downloads this file, but i want register **additional** callback function, called myFunction(data).

**Chrome should download this file and next call myFunction(this xml file).**
I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#my_form").bind('ajax:complete', myFunction);
```

I also tried to use $.post, but after that only callback function is called and unfortunatelly my file is **NOT** downloaded.

Comment: Maybe you can use something like this: http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: Not easy to do, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020168/file-download-complete-callback

Comment: There's really no simple way to do this. I think the best solution would probably be to implement something on the serverside, like you'd do to get the download progress from the server, but where you'd instead poll the server until it tells you the file has been completely downloaded, and then execute a callback etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to `post` asynchronously, download the returned file, and also execute a callback. One possibility is to "fake" a download link:

```
$.post(POST_URL, POST_DATA, function(response) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', 'data:'
    + response.contentType
    + ';charset='
    + response.inputEncoding
    + ','
    + new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(response));
  a.setAttribute('download', DOWNLOAD_FILENAME);
  a.click();
  // file download triggered

  myFunction();
  // additional callback action
});
```

---

### Update

As [Zoran Majstorovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3452582/zoran-majstorovic) mentioned in his comment, you can try this jQuery plugin: http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Just include [the source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js) and then

```
$.fileDownload(POST_URL, {
  httpMethod: "POST",
  successCallback: myFunction
});
```

For security, you need a previously set cookie

```
Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/
```

Comment: Sorry, i can't use download tag due to my application browsers compatibility

Comment: @user3854236 see updated answer with cross-browser compatible solution (haven't tested it myself on IE though)

Comment: can you please show me how to place the cookie? thanks

Answer (score 0):

$(form).submit() is not an ajax, but a form send (usually, POST), so, you can't register any event listener for 'submit response complete' AFAIK.
I'm using the [jquery-file-download-plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/), based on cookies to execute some javascript, as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer, at least according to this similar thread:

[How to do a Jquery Callback after form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534690/how-to-do-a-jquery-callback-after-form-submit)

would be to:

```
$("#myform").bind('ajax:complete', function() {
  // tasks to do 
});
```

[See jQuery documentation for ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is that the submit result will be an html page with an `iframe`. The`iframe` will perform the download and the parent html will perform what ever you like.